# How to prevent a number format exception caused by converting string to an int

Tags: java, int, numberformatexception

So I've been trying to convert my string into an integer, and I'm getting a number format exception. I'm passing a string of 813.0 to the object below but it is failing.

```
totals.setTotalPremium(Integer.parseInt(r.getTotalpremium().replace(",","").trim()));
```

Comment: `813.0` is not an integer. It is a floating point.

Comment: integer does not support decimal values. Either convert to `double` or `float` or pass proper integer value (one without decimal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Double.parseDouble("813.0") as your output returns decimal values.
Integer.parseInt() is helpful only in case of non decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2):

813.0 technically isn't an `int`, since it has a decimal place.  It's a `float`, instead.  Your options are to either strip off everything after (and including) the decimal place, or parse it as a `float` and then convert to an `int` afterward, using whatever method you prefer (i.e. rounding vs truncation).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it to double then extract the int value like this :

```
    Double v = Double.parseDouble("813.0");
    totals.setTotalPremium(v.intValue());
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider whether `setTotalPremium` accepts a `double` or `float`. Or whether it should. If so, use `Double.parseDouble("813.0")` or `Float.parseFloat("813.0")`.

If not, decide which rounding you want. If any. For `813.0` it’s probably easy, you want 813. But what if it was 813.1, 813.5, 813.8?

If you want rounding to nearest `int` use `Math.round(Float.parseFloat("813.0"))`. If you want to reject numbers that are not equal to an `int`:

```
    double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble("813.0");
    if (doubleValue != Math.rint(doubleValue)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not a whole number: " + doubleValue);
    }
```

Edit: In your code you are replacing `,` (comma) with the empty string. If this is to parse numbers with thousand separators, like `1,813.0`, it’s better not to. Instead use a `NumberFormat` and/or `DecimalFormat` for parsing the number that has a thousand separator/s.